# Get file's size in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, filesize

What am I doing wrong?

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSLog(@"%llu", [[fm attributesOfItemAtPath:@"~/Library/Safari/History.plist" error:NULL] fileSize]);
```

The result is always 0.
Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tilde character is not automatically expanded.

You can use [stringByStandardizingPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByStandardizingPath) to expand it, e.g.:

```
[[fm attributesOfItemAtPath:[@"~/Library/Safari/History.plist" stringByStandardizingPath] error:NULL] fileSize]
```

Comment: If I wanted to convert the above value in bytes, kb, mb and gb where do I start?

Comment: fileSize returns the size in bytes. For KB, divide to 1000 depending on OS X version (Post 10.6 1KB=1000 bytes, in 10.5 1KB=1024 bytes).